# Sql Server timeout in SharePoint Environment

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint

I am new to the community. Please suggest what I should improve to make the posts clear to the users.

I am getting following exception when running C# code at PEAK LOAD time in SharePoint machine with SQL Server:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.

As a step towards troubleshooting this issue, what should I do ?

I can think of following:
(i) Increase command timeout value: Will that be foolproof since the load will increase on SQL server in future ?
Or we should think about increasing CPU and memory resources available on SQL server machine ?

(ii) Should we run SQL profiler to see the long running queries or the queries that are causing deadlocks or the transactions that are not committed causing the queries to wait resulting in timeouts ?

Please suggest the best approach to debug this issue.

Comment: Anything interesting in the SQL Server error logs?

Comment: if it is a SharePoint environment, always check the ULS logs. Chances are you'll find something there which you can then share here. Furthermore, don't fiddle with Sharepoint's SQL databases. There's little chance it's SharePoint's problem but rather some kind of configuration that needs to be tweaked.

Comment: matchgeek: I am yet to get SQL server logs.

Comment: @hbulens: I have checked the event viewer logs, and there are warnings like space on disks in lesser than recommended by SharePoint Health Analyzer. From the logs in our product, we have found that there are SQL timeouts. Should I ask for SharePoint logs ? This is because this is something happening on SQL machine that causes timeout ? May be some piece pf code that keeps lock on the sql tables that other queries are accessing ?

Comment: Sounds like the servers are under spec'd.